# Is it possible to have a 'static' react component that can be used globally every page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The case I have is I require a react component that can be used in every page (without replacing the current page and overlaying this component on the page). I understand I could include this component in the render() of every page but I have 1000+ pages and that wouldn't be very scalable. I was thinking if it is possible to have a 'static' react component which is accessible by every page. I am new to react and didn't find any such example online. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What's the point of a static React component? Just save the HTML to a global var and be done with it.

Comment: Put it in the root component. If you don't have one, create it.

Comment: What's slightly confusing is that you don't want to update 1000+ pages, but you suggest a static component that is accessible by every page, which would mean updating all of them anyway. I've submitted an answer below with a few suggestions. I hope it helps, but it's hard to say what you're really looking for unless you provide some code or concrete example.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I don't exactly understand what you mean by saving the HMTL to a global var. Sounds like an ideal case where I would like to reuse that global var everywhere. However, its unclear what you mean by a global var

Comment: @KitFung My app isn't a single page application. It is multipage which is the reason I am hoping I could create a 'static' component to be used by every page

Comment: @Chris The app was designed to be scalable. Therefore, all 1000+ pages calls this function which "does something". However, I am hoping to replace this such feature which was a static js function with a react component. So I would like to replace this function with a react component which can be accessed by 1000+ pages

Comment: Okay, so you want to replace this js function with a React component. Please explain why you cannot have this within render()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definetly possible. Though there are a few options, and the right one would greatly depend on your application. It's hard to say what you need without any code or example, but here are a few suggestions anyway:

---

What you need to do is first import that component into each of the pages you want to load it in. Let's assume this global component is in a separate file called `GlobalComponent.js` and is in the same directory.

`import GlobalComponent from ./GlobalComponent` (note that you can omit the `.js` from filename)

Then in your render function you just write like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    ...

    <GlobalComponent />

    ...
  );
}
```

And that's it! You can pass in props to it if you want like this:

`<GlobalComponent className="style1" />`

and even give it `children`

```
<GlobalComponent>Hello World!</GlobalComponent>
```

If you don't use JSX, you can create this element like this:

```
React.createElement(GlobalComponent, {className: 'style1'}, 'Hello world!')
```

where the 2nd parameter is the props and the 3rd the children.

Both methods would render this:

```
<GlobalComponent class="style1">Hello world!</GlobalComponent>
```

---

If you **don't** want to do this for all your files, then you could alternatively just paste that html before the root react component.

For example:

```
<body>
<div class="global-component"></div>
<div id="main">
  //react stuff goes here. "global-component" is on all pages.
</div>
```

`ReactDOM.render(reactElement, document.getElementById('main));`

---

Another option is like the first option, but you pass in another React Component to the top-level parent React Element and just render it where needed. You can keep passing it on and implemented where you want it. It depends on your application.

---

If you are using react-router you can do something like @The suggested as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I really appreciate it. However, my app isn't a single page application so your 2nd suggestion wouldn't work in my case and the first case requires me to edit 1000+ files which I'm trying to avoid. The app was designed to be scalable therefore. Say I am trying to have a picture on my page when I hit button X and this button X is scattered across 1000+ pages. Right now, button X calls this static function which renders the picture. I am currently transitioning to react.js and would like to replace this static function with a global react component without suggestion1

Comment: I would replace the button with a React Component for that button (e.g `<CustomButton />`). Then use a code editor (like Notepad++ or Sublime) to find and replace all instances of that button across your project. This way you don't have to manually go through those files one-by-one.

Comment: Though, the website isn't very scalable if you have to edit 1000+ files to make a small change, is it? I would really consider a single-page application of React - which is also one of Reacts major strengths.

Comment: @GucciProgrammer Did you have any success with your problem?

Comment: I decided to insert my component using middleware into every page @Chris